# Send *ngFor value as parameter on click

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm making a little application in Angular 2, I'm displaying a table with some data, I wanna get that data when I make a click on my table

Here's the code:

HTML template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let users of usersdata; let i = index">
     <td (click)="data(users.username)">{{users.username}}</td>
     <td (click)="data(users.email)">{{users.email}}</td>
     <td (click)="data(users.id)">{{users.id}}</td>
     <td (click)="data(users.roleId)">{{users.roleId}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is my component:

```
data(data: string) {
    this.selectedParam.emit(data);
    console.log(data);
}
```

When i make click i get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in .../userslist.component.html:22:16 caused by: self.parent._el_24 is not a function
```

Comment: What code is at `/userslist.component.html:22:16`?

Comment: Can you please post your complete component? `selectedParam` should be defined as `EventEmitter` and annotated with `Output()` there.

Comment: you can also try $event in you data($event). $event contains all values and reference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `[(ngModel)]` to make two way binding of your data to your component. like below

```
<td [(ngModel)]="users.username" (click)="data(users.username)">{{users.username}}</td>
```

Also try

```
//$event will hold value and other reference.
data($event: any) {

}
```

You can get more reference in angular2 side on [] and () notation

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a public array in the component as like.

public usersdata:any;

```
data(data: string) {
this.usersdata = data;
console.log(this.usersdata);
```

}
Now you can access in html template

```
<tr *ngFor="let users of usersdata; let i = index">
 <td (click)="data(users.username)">{{users.username}}</td>
 <td (click)="data(users.email)">{{users.email}}</td>
 <td (click)="data(users.id)">{{users.id}}</td>
 <td (click)="data(users.roleId)">{{users.roleId}}</td>
```

```
data(data: string) {
this.selectedParam.emit(data);
console.log(data);
```

}

Above don't keep function name and parameter name same since it will may cause issue. Change name of the parameter

```
data(datavalue: string) { 
  this.selectedParam.emit(datavalue); 
  console.log(datavalue);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

See the [EventEmitter documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html), your custom component should basically look like the example there, implementing the `Output()` directive and an `EventEmitter`