# how to Use element read by ngfor as function parameter

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have this angular peace of code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50%"><b>List rooms </b></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let room of list_room">
            <td><b> {{room}}</b> </td>
            <td><button (click)="joinRoom()">JOIN</button></td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

I need to take the string content of {{room}} and pass it as a parameter to the function joinRoom().

I tried with this link: [Send *ngFor value as parameter on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979895/send-ngfor-value-as-parameter-on-click)

I changed my code with:

```
<td><button [(ngModel)]="room" (click)="joinRoom(room)">JOIN</button></td>
```

but I have a compile error.

How can I do?

Comment: Not sure but try this: `<td><button (click)="joinRoom({{room}})">JOIN</button></td>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the ngModel.

Using this should work:

```
<button (click)="joinRoom(room)">JOIN</button></td>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqnent